# Compute the divergence of $n(x) = -\frac{\Sigma^{-1}x}{\|\Sigma^{-1}x\|}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator

$\Sigma$ is a $n\times n$ positive definite matrix and I have the function
$$
n(x) = -\Sigma^{-1}x
$$
I define another function called $m(x) = n(x) / \|n(x)\|$ where the denominator is the usual L2 norm. I would like to find the divergence of this new function, i.e. find a closed form expression for
$$
k(x) = \text{div} \,m(x)
$$

Comment: For a matrix $A$, you can show $\operatorname{div}(Ax) = \operatorname{tr} A$. Then, I believe you can use the product rule $\operatorname{div} (uF) (x) = \nabla u (x) \cdot F(x) + u (x) (\operatorname{div} F) (x)$, which works for a scalar function $u$ and a vector field $F$.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? You've been here long enough to know that these types of Do-My-Homework-For-Me questions make many of us salty, and go against the MSE Guidelines! -1

Comment: You're right, I tried using the basic definitions, but then I didn't actually know some of the basic properties of the divergence operator

Comment: You have asked an interesting question about knots on July 22nd, and you have deleted it some hours later. Why ? If you have found an algorithm, I would be interested to know it.

Comment: @JeanMarie you are right, I have un-deleted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see that

$$k(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \partial_{x_i}z_i$$

$$\partial_{x_i}n_j(x)=-\partial_{x_i}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\Sigma^{-1})_{jk} x_k=-(\Sigma^{-1})_{ji}$$

and

$$\partial_{x_i}\|n(x)\|=\partial_{x_i}\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n} n_j(x)^2}=\frac{\partial_{x_i}\sum_{j=1}^{n} n_j(x)^2}{2\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{n} n_j(x)^2}}=\frac{2\sum_{j=1}^{n}n_j(x) \partial_{x_i}n_j(x)}{2\|n(x)\|}=-\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n}n_j(x) (\Sigma^{-1})_{ji}}{\|n(x)\|}=\frac{n_i(n(x))}{\|n(x)\|}$$

Hence we can see that

$$\partial_{x_i}m_j(x)=\partial_{x_i}\frac{n_j(x)}{\|n(x)\|}=\frac{\|n(x)\|\partial_{x_i}n_j(x)-n_j(x)\partial_{x_i}\|n(x)\|}{\|n(x)\|^2}=\frac{-(\Sigma^{-1})_{ji}\|n(x)\|-n_j(x)\frac{n_i(n(x))}{\|n(x)\|}}{\|n(x)\|^2}=\frac{-(\Sigma^{-1})_{ji}\|n(x)\|-n_j(x)\frac{n_i(n(x))}{\|n(x)\|}}{\|n(x)\|^2}=\frac{-(\Sigma^{-1})_{ji}}{\|n(x)\|}+\frac{-n_j(x)n_i(n(x))}{\|n(x)\|^3}$$

and so finally

$$\text{div}\,m(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\partial_{x_i}m_i(x)=-\frac{\text{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1})}{\|n(x)\|}-\frac{n(x)\cdot n(n(x))}{\|n(x)\|^3}=\frac{(\Sigma^{-1}x)\cdot (\Sigma^{-2}x)}{\|\Sigma^{-1}x\|^3}-\frac{\text{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1})}{\|\Sigma^{-1}x\|}$$.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\S{\Sigma^{-1}}
\def\l{\lambda} \def\L{\l^{-1}} \def\LL{\l^{-2}} \def\LLL{\l^{-3}}
\def\n{\nabla}  \def\d{\cdot}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\divv#1{\n\d{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Consider an arbitrary vector $(n)$
and its length $\LR{\l=\frob n}$

Changes in these two quantities are of course related
$$\eqalign{
\l^2 &= n^Tn \qiq \l\:d\l = n^Tdn \\
}$$
Construct the normalized vector $(m)$ and calculate how it changes
$$\eqalign{
m &= \L n \\
dm &= \L dn - n\LL d\l \\
  &= \L dn - n\LL \L n^Tdn \\
  &= \L\LR{I-mm^T} dn \\
}$$
Now consider how these quantities change with respect
to $x$ instead of $n$
$$\eqalign{
n &= -\S x \qiq dn = -\S dx \\
}$$
Substituting this into the previous result yields the *gradient*
$$\eqalign{
dm &= \L\LR{mm^T-I}\S dx \\
\n m &= \L\LR{mm^T\S-\S} \\
}$$
The divergence equals the trace of the gradient, therefore
$$\eqalign{
\n\d m &= \L\trace{mm^T\S-\S} \\
 &= \frac{m^T\S m - \trace{\S}}{\frob{\S x}} \\
}$$

Comment: Your expression and @Conformality 's expressions look different. Is there any way I can check numerically which one is correct?